# Guitarix memory allocation error in archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, jack

I've already used guitarix in other distros but now I'm having error trying to use it.
When I start the program (with jackd already runnig through QJackCtl as I always did and worked) it fails wit this error messages:

> [16:17:43]  system init  ***  mlockall failed: [16:17:43]  system init
>
> ***  failed to lock memory: Cannot allocate memory
> [16:17:43]  system init  ***  failed to lock memory: Cannot allocate memory [16:17:44]
>
> loaded state  ***  from file /home/fabio/.config/guitarix/gx_head_rc
>
> [16:17:44]  Jack init  ***  The jack sample rate is 48000/sec
>
> [16:17:44]  Jack init  ***  The jack buffer size is 1024/frames ...
>
> [16:17:44]  PitchTracker  ***  error creating realtime thread - tuner
>
> not started

I've already added my user to the `audio` group and restarted but the error remains.